# Select option values changing on user select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm making a Laravel 5.4 application where users has to select a school and class, when registering their account. I want some JavaScript (JQuery) to change the classes selection option values after which school the user selects.

Which means that $class->school_id has to be equal to the id of the selected school, for the class to show up as an option.

My view:

```
<select name="school_id" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Pick your school</option>

      @foreach ($schools as $school)
        <option value="{{ $school->id }}" required>{{ $school-> name}}</option>
      @endforeach

</select>

<select name="my_class" class="form-control">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Pick your class</option>

      @foreach($classes as $class)
          <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</option>
      @endforeach

</select>
```

Comment: There is no relationship shown between class and school. Add a data attribute for school id to the options so you can filter them. Or use ajax to get appropriate classes when a user selects a school. beyond that this question is far too braod and there are lots and lots of resources on the web for cascading selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add an ajax technology for this ..

**FORM**

```
<select name="school_id" id="school_id" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Pick your school</option>

      @foreach ($schools as $school)
        <option value="{{ $school->id }}" required>{{ $school-> name}}</option>
      @endforeach

</select>

<select name="my_class" id="my_class" class="form-control"></select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('change','#school_id',function(){
    var school_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getSchoolClass",
        data: {school_id: school_id},
        dataType: ,
        success: function(response){
            var newOptions = '<option value="" disabled selected>Pick your class</option>';
            $( response.data ).each(function( index ) {
                newOptions += '<options value="' + $(this).id + '">' + $(this).name + '</option>';
            });
            $('#my_class').html(newOptions);
        }
    });
});
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::post('/getSchoolClass','SomeController@someFunction');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function someFuntion(Request $request)
{
    $data = SchoolClass::where('school_id','=',$request->school_id)->get();
    return $data;
}
```